# Get the value from Table using AJAX and JQuery on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Console Error :Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

- at Object.success (product-slug:12)
- at fire (app.js:9763)
- at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.js:9893)
- at done (app.js:16005)
- at XMLHttpRequest. (app.js:16257)

L

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="showData(this.value)">

<script>
function showData(str) {
              jQuery.ajax({
                 url : 'data/' +str,
                 type : "GET",
                 dataType : "json",
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                    console.log(data);     //Output is {"": 120}, where 120 is price
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;   //Output is [object Object]

                }
        });           
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function get_data($id)
{
    $product_data = ProductAttribute::where('id', $id)->get()->pluck("price","quantity");
    return json_encode($product_data);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/product/data/{id}', 'ProductController@get_data')->name('product.data');
```

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;

Comment: document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;

Comment: In @ArvindMaurya solution, it will print "data" and not what's inside your **data** object.

Comment: @Takachi yes just look at it, apologies for typo

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
function showData(str) {
              jQuery.ajax({
                 url : 'data/' +str,
                 type : "GET",
                 dataType : "json",
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                    console.log(data);     //Output is {"": 120}, where 120 is price
                    $.each(data, function(index, obj){
                    $('#price').html( obj.price);
                    $('#quantity').html( obj.quantity);
                  });

                }
        });           
}
</script>
```